# Почему возвращается nil для Int64?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

Имена клиентов возвращаются корректно, но целые числа (number of awards, number of cars, number of dogs) возвращаются nil. Такое ощущение, что API не проходит (поэтому включается ‘?? 0). Блин, но как тогда проходят имена клиентов в string? Ведь это все тот же API.

Вот мой код:

```
func getAllClients() {
    AF.request("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", headers: headers).responseJSON {response in
        let result = response.value
        var allCli: [ClientsData] = []
        if result != nil {
            let dataDictionary = result as! [Dictionary <String, AnyObject>]
            for clientsData in dataDictionary {
                let cllstname = clientsData["cllstname"] as? String ?? "Error"
                let noofawards = clientsData["noofawards"] as? Int64 ?? 0
                let noofcars = clientsData["noofcars"] as? Int64 ?? 0
                let noofdogs = clientsData["noofdogs"] as? Int64 ?? 0
                let clientsObject = ClientsData (cllstname: cllstname, noofawards: noofawards, noofcars: noofcars, noofdogs: noofdogs)

                allCli.append(clientsObject)
            }
        }
        self.allClients = allCli.sorted(by: { $0.noofawards > $1.noofawards })
    }
}
```

Есть идеи?

Comment: поля с числовыми данными приходят? если да, то что в них?

Comment: Я полный новичок в вопросе кодирования в принципе. Попытаюсь объяснить что приходит =). Когда я строю с print(clientsData), в debug секции приходят данные. Это огромный набор array, в которых есть фамилии клиентов (string), и цифры по указанным ключам. Все данные там есть. Только вот в приложение они не приходят. Возвращаются нулями, несмотря на то, что в дебаге они как бы поступают с API. Вот что приходит в дебаге: ["noofcars": 2, "cllstname": Smith, "noofdogs": 1, "noofawards": 3] ["noofdogs": 3, "noofcars": 1, "cllstname": Ney, "noofawards": 7] и т.д.

Comment: Насколько я понял, кажется эта проблема крутится вокруг NSNumbers, что-то с переводом из int в string???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте и сравните аналогичный пример, который вполне работает

```
func getAllClients() {
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" // сервис для тестирования
    
    AF.request(url).responseJSON {response in
        let result = response.value
        
        if result != nil {
            let dataDictionary = result as! [Dictionary <String, AnyObject>]
            for clientsData in dataDictionary {
                let userId = clientsData["userId"] as? Int64 ?? 0
                let id = clientsData["id"] as? Int64 ?? 0
                assert(userId != 0 && id != 0)
                print(userId, id, "\n============")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проверьте значения в `clientsData`, воспользовавшись точкой останова

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение**

Если у вас числовые значения приходят в виде строк, то можно сделать примерно так (на моем примере - сначала пытаемся привести `AnyObject` к строке, а затем парсим число)

```
let userId = Int64(clientsData["userId"] as? String ?? "0")
```

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не понял ничего абсолютно (полный нуб в программировании). Но я посмотрел на ваши результаты в браузере и на свои. У вас значение к userId и id идут без кавычек (то есть Int, как я понял). А у меня - с кавычками. Выдает "noofcars":"2", например (это я в Postman - pretty view увидел). Может ли в этом быть проблема? Я бы скинул скрин, но не знаю, как это тут сделать в комментах

Comment: @user398509 см дополнение к ответу

Comment: Ок, shmidt9 официально самый лучший программист в мире!!!! Мое почтение и огромная благодарность!!!! Все получилось!!! Данные начали проходить!!!! Есть qiwi кошелек? Хочу отблагодарить (не знаю, надеюсь после этих слов меня тут не забанят)

Comment: @user398509 ухаха наконец-то мой гений признан (лол). В благодарность просто поставьте галку возле ответа